# Can I run code in parallel that is using Entity Framework to insert data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, task-parallel-library

I've seen a lot of posts about this, but I'm still not quite sure what the answer is. I inherited some code that is handling items one by one. It does a bunch of stuff (it's somewhat CPU intensive), then needs to save data to the database, and update the status of the item. It uses EF.

Here is the existing method:

```
private void CheckForThingsToDo(IContainer container)
{
    var finished = false;

    while (!finished)
    {
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("Console Request"))
        {
            var queries = scope.Resolve<IQueries>();
            var commands = scope.Resolve<ICommands>();
            var context = scope.Resolve<IContext>();

            var nextItem = queries.GetNextItem();
            finished = (nextItem == null);
            if (finished) continue;

            using (var transaction = context.BeginTransaction())
            {
                if (nextItem == null) return;

                try
                {
                    commands.ProcessItem(nextItem.Id); // this is somewhat CPU intensive
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to run these in parallel because it's maxing out one core and the rest of the server is sitting there.

```
private void CheckForThingsToDoParallel(IContainer container)
{
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("Console Request"))
    {
        var context0 = new EntityFrameworkRecordkeepingContext();
        var queries = new AccountTransactionQueries(context0, mapper);

        var items = queries.GetItems();
        Parallel.ForEach(items,
            new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
            () => new EntityFrameworkRecordkeepingContext(),
            (item, parallelLoopState, context) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var queries = new Queries(context);
                    var repo = new Repository(context);
                    var commands = new Commands(repo, queries);

                    using (var transaction = context.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        commands.ProcessItem(nextBatchItem);
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                }
                return context;
            },
            (context) =>
            {
                context.Dispose();
            });
    }
}
```

Should something like that work? It works some of the time. But I end up getting this error:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

Each item is a separate thing, so any inserts done in relation to one item should not impact another set of inserts from a different item.

I feel like I might be missing something obvious. Some of the parallel code is me trying to figure stuff out. Any thoughts? I need a push in the right direction.

Comment: how many items are saved in a transaction

Comment: @nickfinity MSDN has a whole article on this: [ef-concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency)

Comment: @Seabizkit The total number of records created in the database in a given transaction is anywhere from a few up to (I'm guessing) 1000 or so, depending on the item. Most are pretty small, but some are bigger.

Comment: @nickfinity then that should be quick!, how many in total then? if the orgnial code only does 1 save at a time then that will be slow and cpu intentive but if its doing 1000 in 1 go that quick, relatively speaking, but if its doing 1000 x 10000 times then well that will be slow. give better understanding of numbers. so for a given run is it total 1000 or just per trans and if per trans then whats the total ball park

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks. That was very helpful. I had missed that article, but it helped me see that something is being updated that I didn't realize. Now it makes more sense.

Comment: @Seabizkit The entire process can take anywhere from a few minutes on a slow day up to 2 hours on the busiest days of the year. At least a few times a month it takes long enough to cause delays in people being able to work. Trying to speed it up. With the link that Ryan shared, I see where the issue is occurring. There is a table being updated that I wasn't thinking about.

Comment: @nickfinity Glad that helped you. Good luck!

Comment: @nickfinity you gain nothing by trying to "parallelize" insertions, quite the opposite. 1K rows is *no data at all*. 1M is some data but not a lot. The main problem is using the wrong tool to begin with - an ORM. ORMs like EF aren't meant for ETL jobs *at all*. What's the *actual* problem? What data do you have to insert and where does it come from? Inserting lots of items in batches can easily be done using eg SqlBulkCopy or similar classes for other databases

Comment: @nickfinity `l because it's maxing out one core and the rest of the server is sitting there.` the server will still be sitting there if the bottleneck is the database (it is). You're using the same network connection to write to the same database using the same disks, same server CPUs. If you send more data than the server can handle you'll only increase blocking and waits. Parallel loads make sense only when you can ensure they don't block each other, and even then we're talking about concurrent SqlBulkCopy operations, to reduce logging overhead

Comment: @nickfinity despite the question's length, it doesn't contain the relevant information. Eg to load Excel or CSV files into a database all you'd need is to use eg ExcelDataReader or CsvReader to get a `DbDataReader` instance and pass it to `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader);`, and get [true minimally logged bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/prerequisites-for-minimal-logging-in-bulk-import?view=sql-server-ver15). That's useful for large files. For many small files though, it *may* be better to load many of them concurrently

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The bottleneck is not the database. It's the calculations and the process of trying to figure out what to insert into the database, so that's the main thing I want to run in parallel. But with the way the existing code is using EF, I can't easily pull things apart. The number of inserts is trivial. I haven't got everything running perfectly yet, but even dealing with the concurrency errors things were running 40% faster.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I appreciate your help. My question could have been better, but I didn't realize what the problem was until I saw Ryan's link and realized that a table was being updated that I hadn't thought about. If I could easily build the records to insert and then run a bulk insert, the insert itself would probably take less than a second.